# Netlify can't compile a typescript project that uses the variable `window`

Tags: typescript, netlify

I don't have any experience with typescript. But I inherited someone else's typescript project.  I've been asked to integrate some custom Google Analytic code to the project.  I did this successfully in my local development environment.  The project works as expected with GA in my local dev environment.

But when I try to deploy the project to netlify, the build keeps failing no matter what I try. Specifically, the build is failing here:

```
4:28:38 PM: ./app/login/Form.tsx:8:27
4:28:38 PM: Type error: Block-scoped variable "window" used before its declaration.
4:28:38 PM:    6 | import { useRouter } from "next/navigation"
4:28:38 PM:    7 | 
4:28:38 PM: >  8 | let window : any = typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : {}
4:28:38 PM:      |                           ^
4:28:38 PM:    9 | 
4:28:38 PM:   10 | if( typeof window !== "undefined" && window ) {
4:28:38 PM:   11 |   window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []
4:28:38 PM: ​
4:28:38 PM: "build.command" failed                                        
4:28:38 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Basically GA requires the existence of the `window` object, and it assumes the `window` object already exists.  I've tried just the line `let window = typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : {}` but then netlify complains about other errors about the type not being defined.

I've also added `{"compilerOptions":{"lib": ["dom"]}}` to my `tsconfig.json` file but that didn't help either.

Is there something else I can try?

---

UPDATE

I temporarily got around the problem by putting all my google analytic code in a plain `.js` file like `gtag.js`.  Then in my `Form.tsx`, I do a `import * as gtag from './gtag.js'`, and now I can access any google related functions by calling `gtag.<whatever exported function or object>`.

Comment: Does calling the variable something other than `window` work?

Comment: You are creating a module scoped variable named `window` which has nothing to do with the global browser window. Yet based on the code it looks like you're expecting to affect the global environment in which case what you're doing is completely incorrect. `declare global { interface Window { dataLayer: unknown[]; } } if (typeof window !== "undefined") window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer ?? [];` is what you are after